# add a new Color scheme to the Rad Studio

Tags: delphi, ide

It's possible modify or change a color scheme (Color SpeedSetting) in the Rad-Studio?

There is an entry in the Windows Registry? or must edit some file?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look easy at first glance.

I found the following under then HKCU path:

\HKCU\Software\CodeGear\ETM\12.0\Color

with the following sub-keys

- List item
- Classic
- Default
- Ocean
- Twilight

Each key has what appear to be color constants but there doesn't appear to be enough constants to make it the right section.

The list of values under each key:

- Auto_TranslatedItemColor
- EditBackgroundColor
- EditForegroundColor IsOEM
- Non_editBackgroundColor
- Non_editForegroundColor
- SelectionBackgroundColor
- SelectionForegroundColor
- TranslatedItemColor
- UntranslatedItemColor UnusedItemColor

That's all I've got, with out spending a lot more time from the looks of it.

It's probably stored in a BPL as a Opentools API object.

Comment: It is indeed hardcoded :( the actual color values can be found the registry in the key: `HKCU\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Editor\Highlight` I could think of a solution, using OpenTools API where one would create an add-on that handled these.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at OP's https://github.com/rruz/delphi-ide-theme-editor, it supplies thousands of themes. Yes, the OP makes one himself.

Thanks for the OP's awesome project.

*Thanks for @Nicholas point out this for me.*

Comment: You do realise that the person asking the question is the owner of the link you supplied...?